# Keep node selection from spreading to PropertySheet

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-platform

I'm developing an application based on the netbeans platform.

The problem I'm having is this; I have a `TopComponent` that contains two panels, A and B,  each with a `ExplorerManager`. I have two `BeanTreeViews` in each panel with different sets of nodes. When I change selection in the A panel, the nodes in the B panel will be created. Now, I'd like to be able to select a node in the B panel and see it's properties in the default property view. But I still have a selected node in the A panel, and therefore the property view only says 'Multiple objects.' Is there any way to keep the selection in the A panel from spreading to the PropertyView?

I'd like to be able to use `NodeActions` on both sets of nodes, and therefore I've added

```
 associateLookup(new ProxyLookup(
                ExplorerUtils.createLookup(PanelA.getExlporerManager(), map),
                ExplorerUtils.createLookup(PanelB.getExplorerManager(), map)
        ));
```

to the `TopComponent` if i only associate PanelA's `ExplorerManager` then this isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok some after testing around I found a solution that works for me. Perhaps I was a bit quick to post this question. Anyway;

In the `TopComponent` I did

```
associateLookup(new ProxyLookup(
                ExplorerUtils.createLookup(PanelA.getExlporerManager(), map)
        ));
```

Then only the Nodes in `PanelA` will be spread to the PropertyView. And then to get the `NodeActions` to work in `PanelB`, I made it implement `Lookup.Provider`, and created it's `Lookup` with

```
lookup = ExplorerUtils.createLookup(explorerManager, map);
```